# How to Start MongoDB as a Service on Ubuntu with a custom DBPath

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu server that was running MongoDB perfectly fine, but the server ran out of diskspace and crashed. I've cleared it out, but now I can't get Mongo back up and running as a service.

This has happened before and I was able to solve it by doing the following:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo mongod --repair
sudo chown mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo service mongod start
```

But now when I do that, I'm getting this error during the repair:

```
exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
```

And when I append the location of the dbpath, I get a different error:

```
 sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --repair
 ...
 Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted
Fatal Assertion 28578
```

What's weird is that, if I run the mongod service independently, everything works great:

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

I'm able to connect to it and everything is hunkydory, but I need this to run as a service so that I can close the terminal window. Any ideas what might be wrong?

I suspect that for some reason, when I run the service mongo start command, it's not picking up the settings in mongod.conf.

For good measure, here's what my /etc/mongod.conf looks like:

```
# mongod.conf
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: false
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


#processManagement:

security:
    authorization : enabled
#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

UPDATE: I was able to make some progress. I copied the /etc/mongod.conf file to /data/db/mongod.conf and it appears to be finding the correct database now, however, now I'm getting a new error:

```
listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
  addr already in use
Failed to set up sockets during startup.
```

Comment: This will happen already mongodb server is running and you are trying to start one more, which is not allowed. 

>`sudo service mongod status`  - will show whether mongodb server is already running. If it is running stop it and try starting the server back with

 >`sudo service mongod start`

As an alternative, you can remove the file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock and restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after my server had crashed.

I was abled to fix it by give the path to the configuration file which contains the correct (custom) db location

```
mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
```